# html img tag not working because wrong path generated Rails 4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a `div` tag in my rails application (*new.html.erb*):

```
<div style="background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat;"> 
</div>
```

The image is not appearing and I get a `ActionController` routing error `No route matches [GET] "/locations/images/background.jpg"`

The problem is that Rails is adding `locations/` to the file path which is wrong since my image is correctly located in *app/assets/images/background.jpg*.
Even if I include the absolute path of the file I'll get `locations` added to the beginning of it.

Here are my routes (not sure if that helps but it won't hurt!):

```
 locations GET    /locations(.:format)          locations#index
              POST   /locations(.:format)          locations#create
 new_location GET    /locations/new(.:format)      locations#new
edit_location GET    /locations/:id/edit(.:format) locations#edit
     location GET    /locations/:id(.:format)      locations#show
              PATCH  /locations/:id(.:format)      locations#update
              PUT    /locations/:id(.:format)      locations#update
              DELETE /locations/:id(.:format)      locations#destroy
```

Comment: `url(images/background.jpg` should be `url(/assets/background.jpg`, yeah?

Comment: No, the images folder is a child of assets, if anything it would be _assets/images/background.jpg_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to generate the url using the `image_path` helper inside your view:

```
<div style="background-image: url('<%= image_path('background.jpg') %>'); background-repeat: no-repeat">
</div>
```

The helper is important, because in production your assets could be fingerprinted or hosted remotely (e.g. on a CDN). The helper will always generate the correct url.

**Edit:**

To reference a background image in a css file, you have two choices. Using base rails, you can add `.erb` to the end of your css filename and use code substitution as above.

**stylesheet.css.erb:**

```
.myclass {
  background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'background.png' %>);
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using the `sass-rails` gem, you can use `image-url` or `asset-url` helpers:

**stylesheet.scss:**

```
.myclass {
  background-image: image-url('background.png');  // or asset-url('background.png');
}
```

See the [Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) for more information.

Comment: This works. What about in the css if I want to include the image as a `background-image:` property?

Comment: Like in an external stylesheet?

Comment: no, in application.css for example (_app/assets/stylesheets/application.css_)

Comment: Edited with stylesheet usage.